# xcscheme generated when install cocoapod. is it safe to be ignored?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

ive been install pod on my project. but it generate xcshceme file. is it safe to ignore it?

`Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Alamofire.xcscheme
Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/AppsFlyerFramework.xcscheme
Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Bolts.xcscheme
Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/CTNotificationService.xcscheme
Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Cache.xcscheme
Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Cosmos.xcscheme
Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Crashlytics.xcscheme
Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ourusername.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Dropper.xcscheme`

Comment: yes,it is safe to ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore `xcscheme` files. You can add it to `.gitignore`.

`xcscheme` are the actions and configurations that happen when you build, run, test, profile, etc. These can be changed from Xcode user to user, which makes it friendly for using on multi-developer projects.

These are the same items you see within Xcode when you click on the "Edit Scheme" popup menu choice.

[image: Edit Scheme Popup]